# Complex Number Solutions

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all complex number solutions $z$ such that

$$\frac {z+1}{i-2z}$$

is real.

How should I approach this question? I tried inserting $a + bi$ for $z$, but it just gets one big mess.

Comment: Same class? $ $

Comment: First, I'd try to eliminate the complex number below. Multiply above and below by (-2a+i(1-2b)), where z=a+bi.

Answer (score 1):

$Hint:$ Write $z=x+iy$, now you have,$$\frac {(x+1)+iy}{-2x+i(1-2y)},$$ now, multiply the numerator and denominator with the conjugate of the denominator, and put the imaginary term i.e. the coefficient of $i,=0$.

Comment: A good approach. I think it is best to learn to do some complex number manipulations without explicitly expressing them in the form $x+iy$. So in our case multiply top and bottom by $-i-2\bar{z}$.

Comment: @ André Nicolas,Yes, this too holds good.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Actually in the case of the asker I think it is best that he get his hands on the coordinates themselves, since it is hardly "one big mess" and deserves a decent attempt anyway. =)